# Neo4J: cypher for relations

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

I have a hierarchy in the following format:

Application.A <-[:belongs_to {roles:instance}]-Instance.A1-[:depends_on {roles:host}]-> Host.vm1

implying Application A has an instance A1 which is running on Host vm1 with the relation "belongs_to" and "depends_on".

Instance.A1-[:depends_on {roles:instance}]-> Database db1 <-[:belongs_to]-Instance.dbNode1-[:depends_on {roles:host}]-> Host.vm2

implying instance A1 of Application A depends on Database db1 that has an Instance dbNode1 running on Host vm2.

I am able to write individual cyphers and process the result in my java API.

I am trying to write a a single cypher that will take Application as input (in this case A) & return the whole hierarchy.

Something like this....

A.A1.vm1.db1.dbNode1.vm2

Is this doable? If yes, would appreciate some pointers.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `A1` actually depend on `dbNode1`, instead of `db1`?

Comment: Database can have multiple nodes. So the relation needs to be to the database (since the database does the load balancing).

Comment: I tried the following cypher - not sure if this is the right approach - but works...     MATCH (n {name:'A'})-[*..2]-(p {property:'instance'})--(k) where id(n) <> id(k) return n.name,p.name,  k.name;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is certainly possible.

I would advise against putting, in your relationships, properties that would need to be used for matching purposes -- since Cypher does not allow you to index them yet. You should just have specific relationship types.

Also, to indicate which instance of the `db1` DB is being used by `a1`, you really need a direct relationship between `a1` and `dbNode1`. You cannot only have a relationship between `a1` and  `db1`, since it would not be clear which instance of `db1` is being used by `a1`.

Here is an example of what you could do:

```
MATCH
  (a1:Instance)-[:is_instance_of]->(a:Application {name: "MyApp"}),
  (a1)-[:runs_on_host]->(vm1:Host),
  (a1)-[:uses_db_type]->(db1:Database),
  (a1)-[:uses_db_instance]->(dbNode1:Instance)-[:is_instance_of]->(db1),
  (dbNode1)-[:runs_on_host]->(vm2:Host)
RETURN a.name + "." + a1.name + "." + vm1.name + "." + db1.name + "." + dbNode1.name + "." + vm2.name AS result;
```

Note that this simple query would not match an app instance that does not use a DB. If you need to match such instances as well, you can use an `OPTIONAL MATCH` clause:

```
MATCH
  (a1:Instance)-[:is_instance_of]->(a:Application {name: "MyApp"}),
  (a1)-[:runs_on_host]->(vm1:Host)
OPTIONAL MATCH
  (a1)-[:uses_db_type]->(db1:Database),
  (a1)-[:uses_db_instance]->(dbNode1:Instance)-[:is_instance_of]->(db1),
  (dbNode1)-[:runs_on_host]->(vm2:Host)
RETURN
  CASE WHEN db1 IS NULL THEN a.name + "." + a1.name + "." + vm1.name
       ELSE a.name + "." + a1.name + "." + vm1.name + "." + db1.name + "." + dbNode1.name + "." + vm2.name
       END
  AS result;
```

Comment: Excellent.. this fits exactly to what I was looking for !!